# Access database config variables from a helper in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to get the database.php variables values from a helper in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is the way, normally you won't be able to use `$this` in helper, so you have to use `get_instance()`. I have given an example of 'hostname' you can use the config name you need.

```
   function test()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();
        echo $CI->db->hostname; // give the config name here (hostname).
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$ci=& get_instance();
$ci->config->load('database');
$ci->config->item('item name');
```

**If** you want to access the config file for the database when $this->config->load(); is *not available*, the solution could look like this:

```
include(APPPATH.'config/database'.EXT);
$conn = mysql_connect($db['default']['hostname'], $db['default']['username'], $db['default']['password']);

mysql_select_db($db['default']['database'], $conn);
```

Comment: Another one is still there "If you want to access the config file for the database when `$this->config->load();` "     Thanks

Comment: Usman, read the last section of that sentence. IF $this and get_instance(); is NOT available, you can load the config file with that code. (For an example, if you're creating a MY_Security.php)

Answer (score 1):

My easiest fix was

```
include_once APPPATH . 'config/database.php';
echo json_encode($db); // contains all the database configurations
```