# Is it possible to use multiple $this within a helper in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a form error logger, but since my register.php controller is getting full I thought of moving this to a helper but the problem is I cannot use $this.

Yes I have checked and there are some anwsers that fix this problem by using:

```
function test()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    echo $CI->db->hostname; // give the config name here (hostname).
}
```

(Quoted from [Acess database config variables from a helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242413/access-database-config-variables-from-a-helper-in-codeigniter))

However my problem with this it that I can only use one model per function and seeing as my code I am trying to move is this:

```
function submitCheck() {
    $this->load->model("User");
    if(empty($post)) { //If anything is empty the view will be loaded
        $this->load->view('includes/header.php');
        $this->load->view('error_message.php'); 
        $this->load->view('includes/footer.php'); 

        if(empty($post['firstname'])) //This is for the error log
        {  
            $this->load->helper('array', 'error'); //Loading the helper
            echo $msg = errorLog('firstname');
            $this->load->view('error_message.php');
        }        

        if(empty($post['mail'])) //This is for the error log
        {
            $this->load->helper('error'); //Loading the helper
            echo $msg = errorLog('mail');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Everything is filled in";
    }
}
```

So if following the code example i'd have to make around 4/5 functions for every $this. Should I create a loader that in term loads other loaders or can I use the user_loader to load other views/models as well.

I am a starter with codeIgniter so I might've just thinked too difficult and there is an easy fix but I can't find it. Any help is appriciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need to use helper library more than one time then place this within constructor(_i.e. public function __construct()_) instead of calling redundantly

Comment: If you mean adding the user_loader function to the constructor wouldn't I still need to load multiple models/views? If so do you know how I should change my loader function

Comment: You should understand the language you are using (before the framework). The topic of your question is somewhat misleading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php

Comment: I see, I shall read through that question then sorry for the misleading title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to CodeIgniter [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html#helper-functions):

> Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in
>   an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each
>   helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on
>   other functions.

It's not recommended to use helpers in your case. It's better to define your custom library for managing much of your codes.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I should move my function (submitCheck) to a library for example submitClass, then call the functions via `$this->load->submitClass->submitCheck();`